# Edit an array value using another array with the positions that should change

Tags: python

It's the end of my first month coding with python and I'm struggling with a piece of code that seemed simpler in my mind.

I'm trying to edit array values based on the positions given by another array generated by `np.argwhere`. For example:

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

b = np.argwhere(a>3)

c = ([7,8,9],[10,11,12])
```

Now I want to change the values in `c` that are in the same position as the values that are greater than 3 in the array `a`.

I'm trying to avoid a for loop because of the size of the real data I am working on.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any particular reason you are using `argwhere` and not `where`?

Comment: I thought it was easier, haha, turns out I was wrong ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` indexing:

```
In [6]: c[np.where(a>3)] = a[a>3]

In [7]: c
Out[7]:
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [10,  4,  5]])
```

Comment: It worked with my data!!! Thank you very much! I had already tried with indexing this way but never got the right arguments in place!

Comment: Glad to help, happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

cant you just do

```
c[a>3] = a[a>3]
```

example:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.arange(7,13).reshape(2,3)
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

c[a>3] = a[a>3]
```

outputs

```
>>> c
[[ 7  8  9]
 [10  4  5]]
```